# DLIB correlation tracker Bounding box follow object problem

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, dlib

hello i have the a python code that read my webcan and in loop o start a face detection and after that i start a track of bounidng box.

```
import cv2
import dlib

status ="D"
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# initialize the correlation tracker.
tracker = dlib.correlation_tracker()

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if status =="D":
        #Do my face detect here
        if len(face)==1:
            status = "T"
            tracker = dlib.correlation_tracker()
            rectDlib = dlib.rectangle(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3])
            tracker.start_track(roiFrameRGB[i], rectDlib)
    else:
        continue

    roiFrameRGB = func.bgr2rgb(frame)
    trc = tracker.update(roiFrameRGB)
    pos = tracker.get_position()
    startX = int(pos.left())
    startY = int(pos.top())
    endX = int(pos.right())
    endY = int(pos.bottom())
    cX = int((startX + endX) / 2.0)
    cY = int((startY + endY) / 2.0)
```

its just a basic example of dlib tracker traking the first face detected.

The code is working but my huge problem is. some times whem a move my face in front the camera its start to track and im some time the tracker stops to follow my face.

there is a way to prevent it or improve the tracker confidence?

im printing `trc` variable and my confidence never decrease under 10.

Comment: dlib appears to implement the "MOSSE" tracker. it doesn't "just stop", does it? it slips off the tracked object, right? please give more detail on the behavior you see. post a video to be most helpful.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz. Yes your right . my object start to move and the tracker dont follow him.

Comment: this tracker can't fix that. it doesn't detect objects. you'll either have to augment this with face detection (kinda like how GPS + IMU complement each other), or pick another tracker that learns the tracked object's shape with more persistence.

Comment: do you know any more acurate tracker? that can be run in a raspberry p4 ?

Comment: this tracker can be subpixel (!) accurate, it's just not very smart. I don't know about dlib. OpenCV has a whole tracker module and a bunch of sample codes using the DNN module.